# Go ctx.Done() never firing in select statement

Tags: go, backend

I have the following code for a module I'm developing and I'm not sure why the `provider.Shutdown()` function is never called when I called `.Stop()`

The main process does stop but I'm confused why this doesn't work?

```golang
package pluto

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sync"
)

type Client struct {
    name string
    providers []Provider
    cancelCtxFunc context.CancelFunc
}

func NewClient(name string) *Client {
    return &Client{name: name}
}

func (c *Client) Start(blocking bool) {
    log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Starting the %s service", c.name))

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    c.cancelCtxFunc = cancel // assign for later use

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, p := range c.providers {
        wg.Add(1)

        provider := p
        go func() {
            provider.Setup()

            select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    // THIS IS NEVER CALLED?!??!
                    provider.Shutdown()
                    return
                default:
                    provider.Run(ctx)
            }
        }()
    }

    if blocking {
        wg.Wait()
    }
}

func (c *Client) RegisterProvider(p Provider) {
    c.providers = append(c.providers, p)
}

func (c *Client) Stop() {
    log.Println("Attempting to stop service")
    c.cancelCtxFunc()
}
```

Client code

```golang
package main

import (
    "pluto/pkgs/pluto"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    client := pluto.NewClient("test-client")

    testProvider := pluto.NewTestProvider()
    client.RegisterProvider(testProvider)

    client.Start(false)

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    client.Stop()
}
```

Comment: It is likely that the program terminates before the select statement has a chance to run.

Comment: Not to mention you almost guaranteed to be in the `default` case blocked by `provider.Run`, so how could you ever revisit the `<-ctx.Done():` case?

Comment: @BurakSerdar I think you're right. I just realized if I do a time.Sleep after calling the cancel func then the code works. Is it possible to setup a 30 second max timeout but cancel earlier if everything is finished?

Answer (score 1):

Because it's already chosen the other `case` before the context is cancelled. Here is your code, annotated:

```
    // Start a new goroutine
    go func() {
        provider.Setup()
        
        // Select the first available case
        select {
            // Is the context cancelled right now?
            case <-ctx.Done():
                // THIS IS NEVER CALLED?!??!
                provider.Shutdown()
                return
            // No? Then call provider.Run()
            default:
                provider.Run(ctx)
                // Run returned, nothing more to do, we're not in a loop, so our goroutine returns
        }
    }()
```

Once `provider.Run` is called, cancelling the context isn't going to do anything in the code shown. `provider.Run` also gets the context though, so *it* is free to handle cancellation as it sees fit. If you want your routine to also see cancellation, you could wrap this in a loop:

```
    go func() {
        provider.Setup()

        for {
        select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                // THIS IS NEVER CALLED?!??!
                provider.Shutdown()
                return
            default:
                provider.Run(ctx)
        }
        }
    }()
```

This way, once `provider.Run` returns, it will go through the `select` again, and if the context has been cancelled, that case will be called. **However**, if the context *hasn't* been cancelled, it'll call `provider.Run` *again*, which may or may not be what you want.

EDIT:

More typically, you'd have one of a couple scenarios, depending on how `provider.Run` and `provider.Shutdown` work, which hasn't been made clear in the question, so here are your options:

`Shutdown` *must* be called when the context is cancelled, and `Run` must only be called once:

```
go func() {
    provider.Setup()
    go provider.Run(ctx)
    go func() {
        <- ctx.Done()
        provider.Shutdown()
    }()
}
```

Or `Run`, which already receives the context, already does the same thing as `Shutdown` when the context is cancelled, and therefore calling `Shutdown` when the context is cancelled is wholly unnecessary:

```
go provider.Run(ctx)
```

Comment: Thanks! do you have any ideas how i'd just get provider.Run to run once? (provider.Run will be potentially blocking e.g. it might run a HTTP server inside)

Comment: @Calum: is there a reason you're not just running `<-ctx.Done(); provider.Shutdown()` concurrently?

Comment: You could use a flag, there's lots of solutions really - but at the heart of it, this design is quite probably incorrect from the start. Specifically, I question whether you need to call `provider.Shutdown` a) if `provider.Run` has already been called and returned, and b) if the context passed to `provider.Run` has been cancelled. I would think that in both cases the answer is "No", which means you could replace the entire loop and `select` with simply `provider.Run(ctx)`.

Comment: @Calum see edits - in typical Go code there are two common possibilities here, Jim's being one and the other being that none of this code is necessary.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I appreciate the help.